# Конфигурация URL-путей с использованием JAX-RS (RESTeasy).

Tags: java, rest, jboss, wildfly, jax-rs

Имеется сервис, имеющий развёрнутое URL-древо. Весь сервис работает на JAX-RS (точнее RESTeasy под WildFly). Всё работает прекрасно, но недавно возникла проблема: можно ли каким-либо образом обрабатывать запросы вышедшие за пределы древа? То есть, например, существует несколько описанных URL цепочек вроде:

`/users/`

`/users/{id}/`

`/users/{id}/connect`

И так далее. При этом в `users` кроме {id} нет никаких подпутей. Предположим, что вдруг к сервису приходит запрос по пути: `/users/smth/`, то есть по пути неописанному в сервисе. И вот здесь и начинается проблема, сервер выдаёт exception и возвращает пустой ответ. Можно ли как-то кастомизировать обработку таких, неописанных путей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно в таком случае пишется и регистрируется `ExceptionMapper` под конкретный тип исключений. В случае с кривыми путями это скорее всего будет `NotFoundException`.

Итого мы можем написать что-то такое:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {
    Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        // реализуем тут логику
    }
}
```

Аннотация `@Provider` позволяет RESTEasy самостоятельно найти ваш класс (как `@Component` в Spring).